# How can I use tqdm to add a progress bar in this function?

Tags: python

I have received from one colleague a Python script but (due to the large amount of data and the time processing) I would like to include a progress bar to check at each time its progress.

```
from Bio import SeqIO 
from tqdm import tqdm
import csv 
import pandas as pd 
import re 
import time


# Find code in "metadata_silva_simplified.txt" file
path_to_file = "metadata_silva_simplified.txt" 
df = pd.read_csv("Name.csv")
counter = 0
Code=[]
Names=[]
Missing=[]
t = time.time()
for index in df.index:
    #print("------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    #print(str(counter) + "- " + df["0"][index])
    name=str(df["0"][index])
    with open(path_to_file,"r") as file:
        for line in file:
            coincident=0
            ref=line[(line.find("|")+1):]
            ref=ref[:(ref.find("|")-1)]
            ref=ref.strip()
            if name == ref:
            #if ref.find(name) != -1:
                 coincident=1
                 position = line.find("|")-1
                 Code.append("kraken:taxid|" + line[:position])
                 Names.append(name)
                 #print("kraken:taxid|" + line[:position])
                 break
        if coincident==0:
            Missing.append(name)
        counter += 1
        if  (counter%1000) == 0:
            print(str(round(counter/5105.08))+"% completed")
            

Code = {'Code':Code,'Name':Names}
dfcodes = pd.DataFrame(Code) 
dfcodes.to_csv("Codes_secondpart.csv", index=False)
missing = pd.DataFrame(Missing)
missing.to_csv("Missing_secondpart.csv", index=False)
elapsed = time.time() - t
print("Mean time per sample=" + str(elapsed/counter))
```

I thought incorporating the progress bar through the use of tqdm Python tool, but I don't know how to include in the previous function attached above to run it.

Comment: check out [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm).

Answer (score 1):

You already imported tqdm. Wrap your loop in a tqdm call and it should work:

```py
for index in tqdm(df.index):
```